# anchors.length in javascript is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Its very strange condition for me but anchors.length only give total number of anchors when i place script after all anchors tag and when i place before all anchors it gives zero....so i did this but now function lngt() is not returning length of anchors please help me i just stuck..

here is my code

```
<div class="box">
 <script>
 var na;
 na = lngt();
 for(i = 0 ; i < na ; i++)
{
    txt = document.anchors[i].innerHTML;
    lnk = document.anchors[i].name;
    document.write( "<a href='#"+lnk+"'>"+ txt + "</a></br>");
 }
 </script>
 </div>


<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
     <br/><br /><br/><br/><br/>
<a name="a">anchor 1</a><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br   
/><br/><br/><br/>
<a name="b">anchor 2</a><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br 
/><br/><br/><br/>
<a name="c">anchor 3</a><br/>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br
/><br/><br/><br/>
<a name="d">anchor 4</a><br/>


<script>
function lngt(){
var nc = document.anchors.length;
return nc;
}
</script>
```

When i put both script at the end its working fine :/
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Is the `]` at the end of the `lngt` function a typo?

Comment: When you place it before the `<a>` tags, it won't work because the script runs before the tags exist.

Comment: Tip: you don’t have to abbreviate every word. Also, move the entire script beneath the HTML. The function doesn’t exist yet. The elements don’t exist yet. *Nothing exists.*

Comment: That's like me showing up to your house with 10 people and asking you how many of them are inside before we come inside.

Comment: You may also be interested in learning about function hoisting: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: so how can i get anchors.length in upper script ??

Comment: ] was typing mistake!!

Comment: @RocketHazmat but when i put this code at the end it works fine!!

Comment: @MaqboolUrRahimKhan: Exactly!  The `<a>` tags exist at that point, so it works.

Comment: hey @JoeFrambach nice link..but i dnt hav any prblm in function i just hav a prblm in anchors.legth object...

Comment: @RocketHazmat trust me i didnt get it but i want to say you that anchors.length is not working if i place script before all anchors why ??

Comment: @MaqboolUrRahimKhan: *Before* the anchors are created there are zero of them.

Comment: @RocketHazmat can u giv me some suggestion or idea that what should i do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ye4N6/)**

- Wait for your elements to load (use DOM ready, or `window.onload`, or add the `script` tag after your HTML elements).
- Use `innerHTML` to put new elements in your page.

---

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var anchors = document.anchors;
    var toc = document.getElementById('toc');
    for (var i = 0, l = anchors.length; i < l; i++) {
        toc.innerHTML += '<div><a href="#' + anchors[i].name + '">' + anchors[i].innerHTML +'</a></div>';
    }
};
</script>

<div id="toc"></div>

<a name="a">anchor 1</a>
<a name="b">anchor 2</a>
<a name="c">anchor 3</a>
<a name="d">anchor 4</a>
```

Comment: @MaqboolUrRahimKhan: `window.onload` waits until the DOM is ready before running.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function (in the upper `<script>` block) before the elements exist.

Comment: In fact, the function doesn’t exist either.

Comment: The function does exist: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Comment: @JoeFrambach: Functions aren’t hoisted across `<script>` blocks, probably because of nonsense like this. http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/LWuEw/